# Pipes and Filters with the RabbitMqBundle

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq, pipe

I am trying to create a pipes and filters (http://www.eaipatterns.com/PipesAndFilters.html) implementation with the RabbitMqBundle. The final setup should look like this:

```
[main_topic_exchange]

   |---BK=S1.K1---> consumer1.1 ---BK=S2.K1---> consumer2.1---> ...
   |---BK=S1.K2---> consumer1.2 ---BK=S2.K2---> consumer2.2---> ...
                             ...............
   |---BK=S1.Kn---> consumer1.n ---BK=S2.Kn---> consumer2.n---> ...
```

Basically I need to be able to configure a pipe "blueprint" and start as many pipe instances as I need (for scalability).

- Each pipeline, or the first consumer from the pipe, is binded to an exchange (e.g BK=S1.k1)
- Messages are passed from one computing stage (e.g BK=S2.K1) to the next
- Each queue is exclusive
- Message order through the pipeline must be guaranteed
- Processes will be managed with supervisord

My solutions:

1. Use the existing bundle and code the producer and the routing key that indicate the next stage directly in the callback - not too flexible, to hardcoded
2. Extend the rabbitmqbundle and create consumers that have a routing key setter method and pass it from the command line:

`./app/console rabbitmq:pipe1_consumer1 --route=S1.K1 --next=S2.K1
 ./app/console rabbitmq:pipe1_consumer2 --route=S2.K1 --next=S3.K1
 ./app/console rabbitmq:pipe1_consumer2 --route=S2.K1 --next=S3.K1`

--next will indicate the routing key to the next computing stage (consumer).

I am not sure what would be the most elegant solution, any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RabbitMQBundle author here. The bundle's original goal was to implement several messaging patterns. Considering that Pipes and Filters is just another pattern, the best would be to implement it and add it to the library. I would welcome such addition.

Comment: I have implemented the pattern into the bundle https://github.com/tiborb/RabbitMqBundle. It's still under development, but you can get an impression.